# Fluent NHibernate one to many uni-directional mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have Post and Comment classes, and they have a one to many relationship where Post has a list of Comments. How can I map this as a uni-directional relationship with Fluent NHibernate, since a comment does not need to know its parent Post?  Currently, this is my mapping for Comment:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Body);
References(x => x.User);
```

and for Post:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Title);
HasMany(x => x.Comments)
    .Inverse()
    .WithKeyColumn("PostId")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

This doesnt work because when I try to save a Post instance with a newly added Comment, the foreign key on Comment (PostId) is left NULL.  And of course a comment cannot be saved with a NULL PostId.  I've tried removing the .Inverse() clause, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Ran into this myself. Very annoying limitation IMO.

Comment: It is possible with NH3.1 and above, see my answer to another simmilar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466153/nhibernate-configuration-for-uni-directional-one-to-many-relation/7601312#7601312

Answer (score 22, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't support this mapping when you have a not-null constraint on your foreign key. If you remove that constraint, you'll see that NHibernate inserts the Comments with a null PostId, then updates them with the Id of the new Post.

You either need to:

1. Remove the not-null constraint *and* the `Inverse` call
2. Keep the constraint, and map the other side of the relationship (making this a bi-directional relationship, and allowing `Inverse` to work correctly)

This is covered in the [NHibernate documentation for one-to-many's](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany), see the *Very Important Note* at the end.

Comment: No it isn't. The site may have been down temporarily, but the link is definitely still valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a shame NH works this way, I see no reason why it should.