# One to One or Zero relationship with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Given two tables:

```
 ___________
|Table1     |
|-----------|
|Id         |
|___________|
 ___________
|Table2     |
|-----------|
|Id         |
|Table1_Id  |
|___________|
```

Where Table2 record doesn't neccesserily have to exist (i.e. the relationship is *One{Table1}-to-OneOrZero{Table2}*).

I need to be able to Save and Retrieve data from both tables using a parent class, which is mapped to Table1.

The entities are as follows:

```
public class Table1
{
   int Id {get; set;}
   Table2 Table2 {get; set;}
}
public class Table2
{
   int Id {get; set;}
}
```

...I've created the mappings as follows:

```
public class Table1Map
{
   this.Id(x => x.Id);
   HasOne(x => x.Table2).Cascade.All();
}

public class Table2Map
{
   this.Id(x => x.Id);
}
```

...which works fine for reading but not writing the data, because it tries to insert NULL into `Table2.Table1_Id` column instead of taking it from `Table1.Id` property.

Is there a way to make this work for inserts without having to create a bi-directional reference, i.e. without `Table1` property on `Table2 class`?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this question in SO. As far as relationship goes, as already mentioned by @Hacked it can't be HasOne because they are not sharing a common primary key. Consider using HasMany (not really sure) and missing part for unidirectional relationship is `Not.KeyUpdate`

```
public class Table1Map
{
   this.Id(x => x.Id);
   HasMany(x => x.Table2)
   .Not.KeyUpdate() <--here
   .Cascade.All();   
}
```

Below are the reference links

[NHibernate configuration for uni-directional one-to-many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466153/nhibernate-configuration-for-uni-directional-one-to-many-relation/7601312#7601312)

[NHibernate still issues update after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468668/nhibernate-still-issues-update-after-insert/11576097#11576097)

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you'd just uses `References` rather than `HasOne`. See [I think you mean a many-to-one, sir](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/).

Article summary: `HasOne`, or one-to-one relationship, is specifically for a relationship where the two tables share a primary key.

Comment: sorry, I have a different situation since `Table 1` ("`Customer`") doesn't have a `Table2_Id` column ("`AddressId`").