# HasMany mapping with non-nullable key column

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to achieve a `HasMany` mapping with a non-nullable key column.

My mapping looks like this:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<DataExportTable> mapping)
{
    mapping.Table("data_export_tables");
    mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("data_export_tables_id")
           .GeneratedBy.Sequence("SQ_DATA_EXPORT_TABLES_ID");
    mapping.HasMany(x => x.Columns)
           .KeyColumn("table_id")
           .Not.KeyNullable()
           .Not.KeyUpdate()
           .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}
```

The code to save the entity looks like this:

```
var table = new DataExportTable("table_name");
table.Columns.Add(new DataExportColumn("column_name"));
session.Save(table);
transaction.Commit();
```

This throws an exception:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.Orac
>   leException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYSCHEMA"."DATA_EXPORT_COLUMNS"."TABLE_ID")

Now, I read quite a few posts about this topic and the generally accepted solution seems to be to make the reference bi-directional, i.e. adding a `Table` property to `DataExportColumn` and setting that.
Another "hack" is to make the foreign key column nullable.
That's not what I want. I want NHibernate to insert the ID directly in the INSERT statement.
According to the log file, NHibernate certainly knows the ID at the time it executes the INSERT statement:

> NHibernate: select SQ_DATA_EXPORT_TABLES_ID.nextval from dual
>   NHibernate: Batch commands:
>   command 0:INSERT INTO data_export_tables (NAME, data_export_tables_id) VALUES (:p0, :p1);:p0 = 'table_name' [Type: String (0)], :p1 = 93 [Type: Int32 (0)]
>
> NHibernate: Batch commands:
>   command 0:INSERT INTO data_export_columns (NAME, data_export_columns_id) VALUES (:p0, :p1);:p0 =
>   'column_name' [Type: String (0)], :p1 = 1228 [Type: Int32 (0)]

As you can see, NHibernate simply ommits the `table_id` column, although the ID is well known - NHibernate passed it as a parameter to the first insert statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close, you need to set `Not.Inverse()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601312/12752).

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Columns)
       .KeyColumn("table_id")
       .Not.Inverse()
       .Not.KeyNullable()
       .Not.KeyUpdate()
       .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

I don't consider making the relationship bidirectional to be a hack and it's usually necessary for querying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly, it still doesn't work :-( `.Not.KeyNullable()` doesn't add the column `table_id` to the insert, it looks just like the one from my question. Removing the `NOT NULL` constraint from the table in the database, I can see, that adding `.Not.KeyUpdate()` will not execute the UPDATE with that column, leaving the data in the database in an invalid state...

Comment: I assume that since you accepted the answer that you got this to work. What made it work?

Comment: The answer below that scored the bounty: I had to update NH. After that, your answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention which version of NHibernate you're using - but I'll note that this appears to have been fixed in version 3.2.0 according to [this jira issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-941).

If you're stuck with another version of NHibernate, I'd suggest making the relationship bidirectional, as it is a MUCH better alternative to using a nullable FK in my opinion.

Comment: Indeed, I was using NHibernate 3.1. Upgrading to the latest version solved this problem. Sorry for taking so long to come back to you, but the upgrade took some time :-)