# Unidirectional one-to-many NHibernate mapping failing when using FluentNHibernate PersistenceSpecification

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a domain model where a `Order` has many `LineItem`s. When I create a new `Order` (with new `LineItems`) and use `PersistenceSpecification` to test the mapping, NHibernate throws a PropertyValueException:

```
var order = new Order() { LineItems = new List<LineItem>() };
order.LineItems.Add(new LineItem());
new PersistenceSpecification<Order>(session)
    .CheckList(o => o.LineItems, order.LineItems) // PropertyValueException
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value LineItem._Order.LineItemsBackref

### Domain model

```
public class Order {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    [...]
}
public class LineItem {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

A `LineItem` on its own is not interesting, and they will never appear without a `Order`, so the relationship is unidirectional.

### Fluent Mappings/Schema

```
// OrderMap.cs
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
HasMany(x => x.LineItems)
  .Not.Inverse()
  .Not.KeyNullable()
  .Not.KeyUpdate()
  .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

// LineItemMap.cs
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

// Schema
CREATE TABLE Orders    ( Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, /* ... */ )
CREATE TABLE LineItems ( Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, 
                         OrderId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, /* ... */ )
```

The foreign key column in the LineItems table is not nullable, so based on [the information in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601312/4160) I specified `Not.KeyNullable()` and `Not.Inverse()` to prevent NHibernate from attempting to insert a `LineItem` with a NULL `Id`.

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.2.400 and FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733 (the current latest versions from NuGet).

Comment: Please can you provide the schema for the DB tables and some code test code that causes the exception? Also the Order and LineItem properties require the Virtual keyword.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided I wrote a test case which worked fine, performing the correct inserts for the order and lineitem. You can download the test VS 2012 project at http://goo.gl/RwF08.

Comment: @penfold Ugh, how embarassing. I suppose I've stripped down my example too much. Thank you for taking the time to do what I should have done myself. :)

Comment: No problem, it took me very little time ;) If you can update the question so the exception is reproducible I'll have another look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because [the `CheckList()` method tries to save each item in the list](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/40d05ae2096811246719470a47d1d30d14c57147/src/FluentNHibernate/Testing/Values/ReferenceList.cs#L16) as soon as you call it. At this point, the parent entity hasn't been saved yet -- That doesn't happen [until you call `VerifyTheMappings()`](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/40d05ae2096811246719470a47d1d30d14c57147/src/FluentNHibernate/Testing/PersistenceSpecification.cs#L50).

Since the relationship is unidirectional, a child entity (`LineItem`) can't be persisted unless it is part of a parent (`Order`), and the exception is thrown. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/212))

I don't have a solution for this yet other than "don't bother testing the list mapping".

Comment: Thanks for posting this and reporting the issue. Before finding it I thought I was being dense... Did you find a solution in the meantime? If not, what do you think of the solution proposed by me in the issue?