# Nhibernate one-to-many element adding

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, mapping, one-to-many

I read many discussions about this, but can't find solution.
[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4469471) I found that in nhibernate version 3 that must works. I use nhibernate 3.3.3

**Classes** Device has many Ips

```
public class Device
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Place { get; set; }

    private Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Ip> _ips = new HashedSet<Ip>();

    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Ip> Ips
    {
        get
        {
            return _ips;
        }
        set
        {
            _ips = value;
        }
    }
}          

public class Ip
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

**Mappings**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="nhibbd" namespace="nhibbd.Domain">
  <class name="Device" table="devices" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name">
      <column name="name" sql-type="character varying" not-null="true"  length="30"/>  
    </property>
    <property name="Place" >
      <column name="place" sql-type="character varying" not-null="true"  length="30"/>
    </property>
    <set name="Ips" inverse="false" cascade="all" generic="true">
      <key column="device_id" not-null="true" update="false"/>
      <one-to-many class="nhibbd.Domain.Ip" />
    </set>
  </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping assembly="nhibbd" namespace="nhibbd.Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Ip" table="ips" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
    <many-to-one name="Device" class="Device">
      <column name="device_id" not-null="true" sql-type="INTEGER" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="Adress">
      <column name="adress" sql-type="character varying" not-null="true" length="12"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Just trying to add device

```
var device = new Device {Name = "D-Link DIR 320", Place = "320 room"};
var ip = new Ip {Adress = "1921680000001"};
using (var session = GetSession)
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    device.Ips.Add(ip);
    session.Save(device);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

And get exception

> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null
>   or transient value nhibbd.Domain.Ip.Device

I want use **inverse="false"** for collection and **not-null="true"** for Ip.Device value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, we firstly always have to properly set the domain model. That means, both sides of the relation must be assigned:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    device.Ips.Add(ip);
    // new line
    ip.Device == device;
    session.Save(device);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

> Later, when we will load data via NHibernate, we would expect that both ends are properly initiated. The same we should do at the moment of instances creation.

I. `inverse="false"`

Now, if you can make the column "device_id" in the table "ips" nullable... that will work. But because you've explicitly declared **inverse="false"** (the default setting), NHibernate must and always will

1. INSERT the record into ips table, with NULL representing the relation to parent (*device_id*) column
2. UPDATE that record with reference id to its parent (*device_id* will be updated with proper device reference)

That will happen always. if the **inverse="false"**

II. **`inverse="true"`**

Because we already mentioned, that both ends of the relation must be defined in the C# anyway - there is simply no need, to not use the power of NHibernate....

Just use the mapping to **`inverse="true"`** and:

- INSERT will be issued to add new Ip record, with its proper relation to the Device (*device_id* column)

That mapping is there in fact for us. To optimize the data handling, based on the trust that we do set relations in code properly.

In general, I would hardly recall situation when inverse on bidirectional mapping would not be used...

Comment: Whether there is a way to leave `not-null ="true"` for Ip.Device value and not manualy set `ip.Device == device;` in code?

Comment: I am trying to say: **It is a bug** in our code to NOT use `ip.Device == device;` This is the Domain model setting. It is how the relation works regardless of the ORM, of the persistence. If it would be our-in-memory-cache-for-play ... none will do that setting. We simply have to. Have to... hope it helps ;) enjoy amazing NHibernate ;)